# how to make sub HTTP request nodejs

Tags: node.js, curl, https, request, httprequest

I have 2 parts php cURL code that work correctly.
I have to implement in NODE JS. I have 2 requests.
First I have to log in, and then do the action.

```
    // login part
    $this->curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://my.example.com/mypage/?regid=" . username 
    . "&password=" . $password . "");
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,30);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_exec($this->curl);

    // action part
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://my.example.com/mypage/action/");
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myFields);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $content = curl_exec($this->curl);
```

I was able to implement the first part, I see the answer (body) in console.log ().

```
const curl = new (require( 'curl-request' ))();

curl.setHeaders([
]).setBody({
'regid': username,
'password': regpass
})
.post(registry)
.then((answer) => {
    console.log('answer', answer.body);
 })
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

But I can not implement the second request. I tried to do like this example:
[how to make sub HTTP request using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540343/how-to-make-sub-http-request-using-nodejs)

As I understand the cookie problem, how can I implement this part?

Answer (score 0):

Just do the second request inside the callback of the first one. Is there a particular reason why you're using `curl`? It may be easier to use a direct HTTP request library like `axios`. Which is all I know so you can translate it into `curl` if you really need that.

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://my.example.com/mypage',
  headers: {
    'X-Example-Header': 'you can send your headers here'
  }
  params: {
    regid: 'you can put your query params here and they will be added to the URL automatically'
  }
  data: {
    // this is the request body data
    regid: username,
    password: regpass
  }
}).then(res1 => {
  // res1.data holds the response body
  // res1.headers holds the response headers
  // if the header you want contains dashes, you have to access it like this:
  // res1.headers['X-Example-Header']
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://my.example.com/mypage/action'
  }).then(res2 => {
    // res2.data === response of second request
  }, err => {
    console.log(err.response.data);
  });
}, err => {
  // this function triggers if the response is a 4xx or 5xx
  // err.response.data is the response body for the error
  console.log(err.response.data);
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: during the second request we are no longer in the login,
I think we should save the session in cookies.

Comment: @Dav Node.js does not store cookies, it is not a browser. You will have to grab the cookie out of the header and put it in a variable yourself.

Comment: bro, all problems in cookie, I get cookie from first response, and sent in second request )))


    var mycookie = res1.headers['set-cookie'][0]


headers: {
            Cookie: mycookie,
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'
        },